# How can I access setter and getter methods from an instance method in a Ruby object instance?

Tags: ruby

This question is about setter and getter methods in Ruby. In the example below, I have three methods. The first two are, respectively, to get and set an instance variable `@login_method`. The third is an instance method that attempts to access the setter method. It fails to access the setter method, because when the line `login_method = 15` is run, execution does not stop for the debugger statement I placed inside the setter method.
Why can I not access the setter method from inside of method `mymeth`? I can access it if I prefix the setter method call with "self", but why do I have to do this?

```
require 'byebug'
class MyClass
  def login_method
    debugger;
    @login_method
  end
  def login_method=(value)
    debugger;
    @login_method
  end
  def mymeth
    debugger;
    login_method = 15
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.mymeth
```

Comment: From [Assignment Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods): _"When using method assignment you must always have a receiver. If you do not have a receiver, Ruby assumes you are assigning to a local variable"_

Answer (score 1):

Your `login_method=` instance method needs a receiver. If this is not important for you and you can make it private this should do the trick

```
private

def login_method=(value)
    debugger;
    @login_method
end
```

Comment: Why is the getter method relevant?

Comment: Because I missed method obviously :D

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
class MyClass
  def login_method
    @login_method
  end
  def login_method=(value)
    @login_method = value
  end
  def mymeth
    self.login_method = 15
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.mymeth
puts obj.login_method
```

You can also do this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :login_method

  def mymeth
    self.login_method = 15
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.mymeth
puts obj.login_method
```

Comment: The OP is aware that it works with `self`, the question is "why?"

Comment: well, was this and was also that the setter method was wrong: it was not assigning the value